# Making a cartesian of tuples does not work

Tags: python

Have the following tuple:

```
t = (('x', (1, 2, 3), ('A', 'B')),
     ('y', (5, 6), ('E', 'G')))
```

How can the tuple be made to a cartesian as follows:

```
(('x', 1, 'A'),
 ('x', 1, 'B'),
 ('x', 2, 'A'),
 ...
 ('y', 6, 'G')
```

The following does not work:

```
from itertools import product
[(product(zip(a[0], a[1], a[2]))) for a in t]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `zip`, just unpack each tuple:

```
from itertools import product

data = (('x', (1, 2, 3), ('A', 'B')), ('y', (5, 6), ('E', 'G')))

result = [p for tup in data for p in product(*tup)]

for p in result:
    print(p)
```

**Output**

```
('x', 1, 'A')
('x', 1, 'B')
('x', 2, 'A')
('x', 2, 'B')
('x', 3, 'A')
('x', 3, 'B')
('y', 5, 'E')
('y', 5, 'G')
('y', 6, 'E')
('y', 6, 'G')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extreme example of XY problem.

Why on Earth would you want that? I really think your real problem is something completely different, and strongly suggest you ask about what you really intend to do.

But just to satisfy the form, here is a way:

```
from itertools import chain, starmap, product
tuple(chain.from_iterable(starmap(product, t)))
```